# Form output outside of container

Tags: functions, search

In my functions file I'm trying to wrap a div around a form but for some reason the form outputs without the div.

```
if (!function_exists('new_header_wrapper')) {
 function new_header_wrapper() {
     ob_start();
     $search = "";
     $search = "<div class='search'>" . get_search_form() . "</div>";
     return $search;
     $output = ob_get_contents();
     ob_end_clean();
 }
 add_filter('storefront_before_header','new_header_wrapper');
}
```

Here is the output:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://my-computer.local:5757/">
                <label>
                    <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
                    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search &hellip;" value="" name="s" />
                </label>
                <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
            </form>
```

Comment: Have a look at what [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) does in the php docs.

Comment: So return immediately ends execution of a function. I changed return to echo and there is no output from the function?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/ i.e. to use 'get_search_form()' in a string operation, you will need to set the '$echo' parameter to false

Comment: Changing `get_search_form($echo = false)` worked but I had to echo that string instead of return. Is that ok? So as of right now it's `echo "<div class='search'>" . get_search_form($echo = false) . "</div>"`